# Kubernetes ingress hostname and IP

Tags: kubernetes

So I deployed my application to Kubernetes using HELM.
In the end it gave me 3 ingresses that each have an IP and a Hostname and I can only access the application if I map the IP to the Hostname in /etc/hosts, I would like to know if there is any work around to accessing the application using the IP since that just keeps loading. Thank you

Comment: Nope, that does not work. Think of ingresses as [name based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) (which it is, basically). What you could do is use a [node port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) for the service, though.

Comment: If your Kubernetes nodes are on bare metal, you could use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) and LoadBancing services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your cluster in a cloud environment, you can look at the [External DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) project and the [helm chart packaged by Bitnami](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/external-dns). That will create a DNS entry for your hosts in your Cloud's DNS service (e.g. Route 53 for AWS or Cloud DNS for GCP) and that will allow you to resolve an external host into the IP for your service.